# Multiple text lines below report selection-screen parameters based on table entries

Tags: abap

Before executing my report I want to display the folders below the selection screen.
The folder names are stored inside a table.
Since I don't know how many entries the table has beforehand, this needs to be dynamic - not hardcoded.

This is what I've done so far:

```
DATA: lt_directories TYPE string_table.
DATA: lv_folders_txt TYPE string.

"Report description with test-checkbox
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b11 WITH FRAME TITLE title.
PARAMETERS: pa_test TYPE c AS CHECKBOX DEFAULT abap_true.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT /1(20) folders.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b11.

INITIALIZATION.
  lt_directories = VALUE string_table( ( `FOLDER1` ) ( `FOLDER2` ) ( `FOLDER3` ) ( `FOLDER4` ) ).
  title = 'This program imports data from the listed folders'.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  LOOP AT lt_directories ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<directory>).
    "TODO: this has to be changed!
    lv_folders_txt = lv_folders_txt && <directory>.
  ENDLOOP.
  folders = lv_folders_txt.
```

This is how the result looks like:
[image: IST-Zustand]

And this is an example of how I want it to look like:
[image: SOLL_Zustand]

Does someone know an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a [docking container](https://help.sap.com/viewer/search?q=%22SAP%20Docking%20Container%22&language=en-US&product=SAP_NETWEAVER_AS_ABAP_752) at the bottom of the screen, and include any "text view" control in it, like the [SAP HTML viewer](https://help.sap.com/viewer/search?q=%22SAP%20HTML%20Viewer%22&language=en-US&product=SAP_NETWEAVER_AS_ABAP_752) for instance:

[image: Selection screen with docking container at bottom]

```
DATA: lt_directories TYPE string_table.
DATA: lv_folders_txt TYPE string.
DATA: go_docking TYPE REF TO cl_gui_docking_container.
DATA: go_html_viewer TYPE REF TO cl_gui_html_viewer.

"Report description with test-checkbox
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b11 WITH FRAME TITLE title.
PARAMETERS: pa_test TYPE c AS CHECKBOX DEFAULT abap_true.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b11.

INITIALIZATION.
  lt_directories = VALUE string_table( ( `FOLDER1` ) ( `FOLDER2` ) ( `FOLDER3` ) ( `FOLDER4` ) ).
  title = 'This program imports data from the listed folders'.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  IF go_docking IS NOT BOUND.
    go_docking = NEW #(
        repid     = sy-repid
        dynnr     = sy-dynnr
        side      = cl_gui_docking_container=>dock_at_bottom
        extension = 180 ). " pixels
    DATA: lv_url   TYPE cndp_url.
    DATA(lv_text) = |<html><body>{ 
            REDUCE #( INIT s = `` FOR dir IN lt_directories NEXT s = |{ s }{ dir }<br>| ) 
            }</body></html>|.
    go_html_viewer = NEW cl_gui_html_viewer( parent = go_docking ).
    data(soli_tab) = cl_bcs_convert=>string_to_soli( lv_text ).
    go_html_viewer->load_data(
        EXPORTING type = 'text' subtype = 'html' size = strlen( lv_text )
        IMPORTING assigned_url = lv_url
        CHANGING  data_table = soli_tab ).
    go_html_viewer->show_url( url = lv_url ).
  ENDIF.
```

Comment: This worked - thanks! I just wish it would not be on the bottom of the screen :D

Comment: @Cold_Class A selection screen has the advantage that it's very simple to create it, but the drawback that you cannot customize it as you wish. If you want the list to be displayed between two parameters of the selection screen, then it would be a different answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont like to generate the dynpro or report at runtime.
If you dont want to dock a control with content.
If there is some limit of the number entries that need to be shown. eg < 100

Then there is a simple option using `SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENTS`
Just use place holder 100 screen comments and Default them to space.
Then set the first N dynamically.

[image]

```
REPORT zdemo_so.
PARAMETERS: p_test TYPE c AS CHECKBOX DEFAULT abap_true.

SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT /5(60) folder01.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT /5(60) folder02.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT /5(60) folder03.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT /5(60) folder04.
"... repeat to ??
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT /5(60) folder98.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT /5(60) folder99.

initialization.
   data lt_directories type string_table.
   FIELD-SYMBOLS: <dirname> type string,
                   <lbl> TYPE any.
   data lbl_nn(2) type n.
   data lbl_pre(6) type c value 'FOLDER'.
   data lbl_name type string.

  folder01 = ''.
  folder02 = ''.
  folder03 = ''.
  folder04 = ''.
  " ... 
  folder98 = ''.
  folder99 = ''.

 lt_directories = VALUE string_table( ( `FOLDERNAME1` ) ( `FOLDERNAME2` ) ( `FOLDERNAME3` ) ( `FOLDERNAME4` ) ).

     loop at lt_directories assigning <dirname>.
         lbl_nn = sy-tabix.
         lbl_name = LBL_pre && lbl_nn.
         assign (lbl_name) to <lbl>.
         <lbl> = <dirname>.
     endloop.
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this for `COMMENT`. It’ll always be displayed in one line. Even using linefeed (or carriage return + linefeed) at the end will not give you the expected result.

```
REPORT ZZZ.

DATA: lt_directories TYPE string_table.
DATA: lv_folders_txt TYPE string.

"Report description with test-checkbox
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b11 WITH FRAME TITLE title.
PARAMETERS: pa_test TYPE c AS CHECKBOX DEFAULT abap_true.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT /1(20) folders.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b11.

INITIALIZATION.
  lt_directories = VALUE string_table( ( `FOLDER1` ) ( `FOLDER2` ) ( `FOLDER3` ) ( `FOLDER4` ) ).
  title = 'This program imports data from the listed folders'.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  LOOP AT lt_directories ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<directory>).
    "TODO: this has to be changed!
    lv_folders_txt = lv_folders_txt && <directory> && cl_abap_char_utilities=>newline.
  ENDLOOP.
  folders = lv_folders_txt.
```

[image: Actual result]

Comment: I don't care if it's a `Comment` or something else (but I didn't vote down :D)